# Как открыть форму по нажатию на строку в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я не особо понимаю, как отследить нажатие на DataGrid. вот xaml разметка:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dg_recipes" Margin="10,249,10,10">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Path='name'}" Width="320"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Время приготовления" Width="280"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

По нажатию на выбранную строчку в 1 столбце, должна открываться форма.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dg_datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var cellInfo = dg_datagrid.SelectedCells;
            int count = cellInfo.Count;
            int columnIndex = cellInfo[count-1].Column.DisplayIndex;
            if (columnIndex == 0)// первый столбец
            {
                //тут открываем диалог
            }
     ;
        }
```